# How to write a scripts that selects from postgres in batches

Tags: postgresql, shell, batch-file, select

I'm attempting to do a select of ~55 millions rows from a postgresdatabase that regrettably timeouts every 30s

I need to write a shell script that does something on the form of
for offset in range (0, 55000000, 100000)
    connect to database
    select id from database where id>offset and `id<offset+100000`
    write select to file

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: why not just run `set query_timeout` before running the statement?

Comment: `psql postgres -c "select 1 as x" -o foo.bar`, [read more about `psql` options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)